# How do I undo the result of the remap of ( to ()?

Tags: vimrc

If my `vimrc` file has the following:

```
inoremap ( ()<Left>
```

which essentially auto-closes a `(`, changing it to `()` whenever I type `(` in insert mode.

How do I undo the change when I don't want that to happen?

Comment: please read the documentation: `:h :iunmap`

Comment: What are the circumstances in which you don't want it to happen? Are you perhaps looking for `:help filetype`?

Comment: When using regular expressions to process just an open parenthesis for example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can bypass mappings (among other things) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>: `<C-v>(` should enter a `(` without executing the mapping.

Answer (score 3):

If you usually want to insert the closing parenthesis and occasionally don't want it to be added, you could define another mapping such as

```vim
inoremap (( (
```

This will allow you to type a single opening parenthesis by pressing <kbd>(</kbd><kbd>(</kbd> quickly.

As this mappings is also non-recursive, it won't trigger the original one.

The only caveat is that Vim will now wait for a brief moment after you type <kbd>(</kbd> and wait if another parenthesis is to follow and which mapping is to be used.

You could choose to map any other sequence but my feeling is that the same character repeated twice is about as fast and easy to remember as it can get.